# Cosmos DB SQL API query tracing

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have many collections in Cosmos DB (SQL API) and many services using the same database. 100s of query executing every minute, Sometimes I can see RU exceeding warning. I know all query is not optimized in all the application.

Is there any way to get all queries and execution time (like SQL server Profiler Trace)?

I tried to enable Cosmos DB `Diagnostic Settings`, but didn't get any way to trace queries

Comment: Please vote - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/37760731-cosmos-db-query-trace-logs, If you think this feature should come outofbox

Answer (score 1):

The way you would have to go about it is enabling `PopulateQueryMetrics` in the SDK.

Ones enabled your queries will have the `x-ms-documentdb-query-metrics` header populated. The value looks like this:

```
totalExecutionTimeInMs=33.67;queryCompileTimeInMs=0.06;queryLogicalPlanBuildTimeInMs=0.02;queryPhysicalPlanBuildTimeInMs=0.10;queryOptimizationTimeInMs=0.00;VMExecutionTimeInMs=32.56;indexLookupTimeInMs=0.36;documentLoadTimeInMs=9.58;systemFunctionExecuteTimeInMs=0.00;userFunctionExecuteTimeInMs=0.00;retrievedDocumentCount=2000;retrievedDocumentSize=1125600;outputDocumentCount=2000;writeOutputTimeInMs=18.10;indexUtilizationRatio=1.00
```

As you can see this needs be to split and parsed but it has a lot of useful info which you can log and query to see a lot of stuff about your queries and their performance.

You can read more about query metrics here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-query-metrics

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm aware of these details. Currently, We have 10+ Microservices and by going this approach I have to change all application data access layer and write custom code to log query and execution metrics.

Comment: Well this is the only option that you really have. If you really need them you need to add them. It is highly recommended to have have dependency logging anyway.